# PHP facebook Login redirect not working in AIR browser

Tags: php, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api, air, facebook-login

PHP Facebook login code works fine in Chrome and Mozilla browsers, but not in the AIR browser.

Facebook Login URL :

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=$config['App_ID']&redirect_uri=$config['callback_url']&scope=email,user_likes,publish_stream
```

Once the user logs in our system using Facebook Login, his details are fetched from the URL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=".$config['App_ID']."&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($config['callback_url']) . "&client_secret=".$config['App_Secret']."&code=" . $_GET['code']
```

Using the CURL function.

Page redirection works as expected if I run code in Chrome, Mozilla, etc. but fails if I run it in the AIR browser(AS3 StageWebView).

Why this is happening?
I am not quite aware of the AS3 StageWebView logic.

Please help.